# Correlations comparison between trialgroup and controlgroup using SPSS

Tags: correlation, spss, paired-data

I am new this community site and I need your help. The data below needs to find out how to get correlations pairs between trial group_store_NBR (store1 as 5) and control group_store_NBR.

> ```
> STORE_NBR YEARMONTH   totSales
> 1           201807     206.90
> 1           201808     176.10
> 1           201809     278.80
> 1           201810     188.10
> 1           201811     192.60
> 1           201812     189.60
> 1           201901     154.80
> 2           201807     150.80
> 2           201808     193.80
> 2           201809     154.40
> 2           201810     167.80
> 2           201811     162.90
> 2           201812     136.00
> 2           201901     162.80
> 3           201807    1205.70
> 3           201808    1079.75
> 3           201809    1021.50
> 3           201810    1037.90
> 3           201811    1008.00
> 3           201812    1121.60
> 3           201901    1051.70
> 4           201807    1399.90
> 4           201808    1259.50
> 4           201809    1198.60
> 4           201810    1346.40
> 4           201811    1212.00
> 4           201812    1185.60
> 4           201901    1525.00
> 5           201807     812.00
> 5           201808     745.10
> 5           201809     896.00
> 5           201810     798.00
> 5           201811     771.40
> 5           201812     879.20
> 5           201901     838.00
> ```

I want to see the correlations between store1(trial group) and store2(control group).

> ```
> Store1(trial group) Store2(control group) Correlations (tot_sales)
>    5                    1                   result=?
>    5                    2                   result=?
>    5                    3                   result=?
>    5                    4                   result=?
> ```

Your answer is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. This looks like a data management question. Why don't you reshape your data, so you will have groups in columns (as variables), and then check the correlations between them? I don't know how you can do this using SPSS (which is [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) any way), but I guess it should be easy.

Comment: I was thinking that doing casestovars but there are numerous store_nbr to correlate. I am looking loop command but i dont how to use it using correlations.